# Consuming a Web service using Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services

Is there a way to consume a web service using JavaScript? I'm Looking for a built-in way to do it, using a JavaScript framework is not an option.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can consume a web service using JavaScript natively using the XmlHttpRequest object. However instantiating this object varies between browsers. For example Firefox and IE 7+ let you instantiate it as a native JavaScript object but IE6 requires you to instantiate it as an ActiveX control.

Because of this I'd recommend using an abstraction library such as jQuery. If that's not an option then abstract the creation into a factory method and check for the browser version.

To use this to make a web service call you simply instantiate the object and then call it's open() method. I recommend this is done async to keep the UI responsive. When invoked async you will get callbacks to your specified async method that will indicate the status of the request. When the status is 4 (loaded) you can take the response data and then process it.

How you process the data will depend on what it is, if it's JSON then you can run it through JavaScript's eval() method but that does have some security implications. If it's XML you can use the XML DOM to process it.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) for more info on the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Just curious. Was JavaScript capable of calling web APIs/services before XHR featured into the language or till that time it was meant *only* for DOM manipulation in HTML pages?

Answer (score 5):

You can create an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_http.asp) if the service is hosted within your domain.  If not, you will have cross-domain issues.

Comment: s/could/will/ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Anytime cross-domain stuff comes up I get a little unsure of what the exact rules are.  I just try to avoid those issues altogether ;)

Comment: What do you mean, specifically, by "cross-domain issues"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object, but since you don't want to use any JavaScript frameworks, you will have to marshal and unmarshal the SOAP envelopes yourself.

Comment: You only have to worry about SOAP envelopes if it's a SOAP webservice.  Some restful web services can just be called and the results read without any pre-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Also check [XML HTTP Request](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html) for a nice info page about using the XmlHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small library written in javascript that can be used as a XML-SOAP client.
I don't know if it works on all browsers but it might help you out. You can find it [here](http://www.guru4.net/articoli/javascript-soap-client/en/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked. It's old (checking for Netscape), was written before all the Ajax tools came out. You do have to handle different browsers -- basically, IE does it one way, and everybody else does it the other way.

```
// javascript global variables
var soapHeader = '<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>'
               + '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"'
               + ' SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"'
               + ' xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance\"'
               + ' xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema\"'
               + '>'
               + '<SOAP-ENV:Header/>'
               + '<SOAP-ENV:Body>';

var soapFooter = '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'
               + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

var destinationURI = '/webservices/websalm';

var actionURI = '';

function callWebService(nsCallback,ieCallback,parms) {
  try
     {
       // Create XmlHttpRequest obj for current browser = Netscape or IE
       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Netscape') != -1)
       {
          SOAPObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
          SOAPObject.onload = nsCallback;
       } else {  //IE
          SOAPObject = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
          SOAPObject.onreadystatechange = ieCallback;
       }

       SOAPObject.open('POST', destinationURI, true);

       // Set 2 Request headers, based on browser
       if (actionURI == '') {
          SOAPObject.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '\"\"');
       } else {  SOAPObject.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', actionURI);
       }

       SOAPObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

       // Compose the Request body from input parameter + global variables
       var requestBody = soapHeader + parms + soapFooter

       // Send, based on browser
       if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Netscape') != -1)
       {
         SOAPObject.send(new DOMParser().parseFromString(requestBody,'text/xml'));
       } else {
         SOAPObject.send(requestBody);
       }
  } catch (E)
  {
     alert('callWebService exception: ' + E);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Was JavaScript capable of calling web APIs/services before XHR featured into the language or till that time it was meant *only* for DOM manipulation in HTML pages?