# call live webservice from simple html page...?

Tags: javascript, html, web-services

I read lots of post here, but don't get specific answer.
I have live server on which I have my web services work properly.
now, I want to create one simple html page through which I call that web service.
with javascript this is possible but what is exact.

I repeat again only html and javascript through which I want to call that web service.

Comment: I hope this article might help you, for your requirement.[http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr) This post would be handly as well.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208051/consuming-a-web-service-using-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208051/consuming-a-web-service-using-javascript) [http://www.hendricksongroup.com/code_call_web_service_javascript.aspx](http://www.hendricksongroup.com/code_call_web_service_javascript.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery to load the data from webservice, but you might need to include jquery js file and your browser(IE) might prompt for security violation and you might need to click yes.

Comment: That I know about IE. and for other I know about jquery js file, without that is that possible like if we give live url of jqury and work with only one single html file...!?!

Comment: yes you can do! try XMLHttpRequest object to load the webservice result.