# What is the simplest way you can call a webservice in JavaScript without Ajax or anything else like that?

Tags: javascript, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consuming a Web service using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208051/consuming-a-web-service-using-javascript)

Please note that I'm still getting used to JavaScript.  Basically I need to write an HTML file that uses Javascript to call a couple of web service methods (from the same server as the HTML file) without using Ajax or probably much of anything else that we'd have to install on there separately.  We already have the web service up and running fine, as well as some JS.  This needs to work for IE, FF, and Chrome, including for computers that are a couple of years "behind the times".  What is a really simple way to do this?  Again, I'm still kind of getting my feet wet with JavaScript, so I'm having a hard time following and using some of the examples I've seen.  Thanks!

EDIT: Here's an example of the kind of thing I've been trying:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello World</title>
   <script language="JavaScript">
      var iCallID;
      function InitializeService(){
     alert("spam");
     try {
            service.useService(<WSDL address>, 
                  "HelloWorldService");
     } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
     }
     alert("spam");
         service.HelloWorldService.callService("HelloWorld");
     alert("spam");
      }
      function ShowResult(){
     alert("spam");
         alert(event.result.value);
     alert("spam");
      }
</script>
```

I get "spam", then "Object doesn't support this property or method", then nothing.

Comment: Ajax is not something that you have to install separately.

Comment: Is Ajax something that you at least have to enable separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, AJAX has been around since donkey's years, really. But since you're not familiar with JS, here's a little copy-paste function you could use:

```
function ajax(url,method,data)
{
    var xhr;//ajax object
    data = data || {};//default ajax request
    method = method || 'POST';
    url = url || 'default/url/ajax';
    try
    {//normal browsers
        ret = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (error)
    {//older IE browsers, including dead IE6
        try
        {
            ret= new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            try
            {
                ret= new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            }
            catch(error)
            {
                throw new Error('no Ajax support?');
            }
        }
    }
    if (typeof ret !== 'object')
    {//if fails (almost impossible)
        throw new Error('No Ajax, FFS');
    }
    ret.open(method, url, true);//open ajax connection
    ret.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    ret.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
    ret.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
        {
            var response = this.responseText;
            //code you want to see executed when the call was successful
        }
    };
    return ret.send(data);
}
```

Usage:

```
ajax('your/ajax/url','POST','id=12');
```

This will send an ajax request back to the server, with a POST parameter `id`, value `12`... play around with that. A few things that can be useful: [JSON](http://json.org), and -though I'm not a big fan- [jQuery](http://jquery.com), it has a ready built-in `$.ajax` method, just pass an object literal and you're good to go.

Feel free to edit this function as you please

Comment: Just curious. Was JavaScript capable of calling web APIs/services before XHR featured into the language or till that time it was meant *only* for DOM manipulation in HTML pages?

Comment: @RBT AFAIK, JS had the capability to connect with server-side technology from quite early on. A quick google search came up with a `liveConnect` call being added back in the JS 1.1 days. I seem to recall the language was originally developed to spruce up the client side in a browser. That said, the DOM API was never (and still isn't) part of JS itself. This is why the language can be moved to server side, and depending on the runtime can be used as a scripting language in applications. It's just a matter of introducing a new object to the runtime

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consume a web service you must create a connection between the running page on the client machine and the server hosting the service. The umbrella term for doing this is AJAX. It is not a separate technology you install but a term that describes the use of the XMLHttpRequest object available in the JavaScript DOM. There are plenty of resources describing cross browser usage...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

And many JavaScript libraries have cross-browser implementations that you can use without worrying about the details. jQuery, MooTools, Prototype... etc.