# Error: Webservice not defined

Tags: web-services, asmx

i have made webservice, and i am trying to consume it using javascript, but when i call the webservice method it gives the error Webservice not defined. I have given reference of it .

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Services>
       <asp:ServiceReference Path="../WebService.asmx" />
    </Services>
       </asp:ScriptManager>
```

my method

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    CultureInfo cul = new CultureInfo("gu-IN", true);
    protected sdData s = new sdData();
    protected component comp = new component();
    public ClsVB objvb = new ClsVB();
    DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess();

    public WebService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string SubmitDDIPo(string txtCaseNoDDIPO, int txtDDIPO, int txtAmount, string txtDDDate, string txtBank, string District_Code )
    {
```

javascript method calling

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function addDDIPO() {
                "DDIPOdiv".Obctrl().style.display = "block";
                "fadeDiv".Obctrl().style.display = "block";

            }
            function submitDDIPO()
             {
                 WebService.SubmitDDIPo("txtCaseNoDDIPO".Obctrl().value, "txtDDIPO".Obctrl().value, "txtAmount".Obctrl().value, "txtDDDate".Obctrl().value, "txtBank".Obctrl().value, Session["District_Code"].ToString(), ResultSubmitSucess, ResultFailure);
             }
            </script>
```

Is that something i am missing?
please help

Comment: what kind of JS library are you using? By default, `WebService` is not a JS object. You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208051/consuming-a-web-service-using-javascript

Comment: Huh? You'd better learn from JavaScript basics, if you don't even know which library you are using. (Hint: to check which library is used, check the scripts you have "included" via `<script>` tag)

Comment: @commenters ankitsrist is in a good way with this. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/bb398995(v=vs.90).aspx.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: thanks i have done by calling webservice with jquery...

Answer (score 3):

Try to uncomment `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`.

If the uncommneted attribute doesn't work check the namespaces. `ScriptManager` create the javascript client proxy whith full path. Ej: `namespace1.namespace2.WSClassName.Method()`. You can also try to put the client proxy inline to see the js source to easyly find it with `ServiceReference.InlineScript` property.